# Where is the default lnddir?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

Looking for my macaroon files which should be at this location:

`lnddir/data/chain/bitcoin/mainnet`

However, I can't figure out where my default lnddir location is. I don't want to set a new lnddir. I'm working on macOS, however information for all major operation systems should be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For macOS: `/Users/arshbot/Library/Application\ Support/Lnd/`